# Link not opening Safari

Tags: objective-c, ios4, rss, mobile-safari

I'm making a basic RSS reader and it should be opening the link in Safari, but nothing happens when I click on the cell. Here is what I have:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Navigation Logic:

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
NSString *storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"link"];

//cleaning up the link...

storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];
storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);

//open in Safari
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];


}
```

Here is the console log:

```
 2011-06-27 20:03:51.817 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] all done
 2011-06-27 20:03:51.818 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] stories array had 20 items
 2011-06-27 20:03:53.758 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] link: technobuffalo.com/companies/apple/…
```

And where I put in the link:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
if ([stories count] == 0) {
    NSString *path = @"http://www.technobuffalo.com/feed/";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
}
```

}

Here is the parsing code:

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *__strong)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *__strong)attributeDict {

currentElement = [elementName copy];
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
    //clear out story item caches...
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

 }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *__strong)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *__strong)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *__strong)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];

    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
}


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *__strong)string{
//save the characters for the current item

if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [currentTitle   appendString:string];
}
else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [currentLink   appendString:string];
}
else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
    [currentDate  appendString:string];
}
else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
    [currentSummary   appendString:string];
}


}
```

Comment: Can you add an example link that is logged?

Comment: 2011-06-27 20:03:51.817 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] all done
2011-06-27 20:03:51.818 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] stories array had 20 items
2011-06-27 20:03:53.758 ParadiseBeats[26927:207] link: http://www.technobuffalo.com/companies/apple/lulzsecs-goodbye-gift-leaks-att-doc-indicating-4glte-ipad/

Comment: Does the link specify a protocol? If it doesn't necessarily use HTTP the finder or some other app might snarf it before Safari.

Comment: Also, it's off topic but you probably want to trim the ends of the link and replace spaces within the link with `%20`.

Comment: @Chris How are you parsing the XML? And does the `storyLink` string have the `http://` suffix when you retrieve it from the `stories` object?

Comment: @Chris Can you add the code where you are parsing the links?

Comment: Have you tesed whether this following line actually works with a string: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];`? I.e. replace `storyLink` with, say, `@"http://www.google.com"`.

Comment: Yes I have copied and pasted one of the story links that are showing up in the console into there and it stil will not open

Comment: @Deepak I added the parsing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depak: your code above is wrong. You need to check for a prefix of http://, not a suffix. It should be:

```
if ( ![storyLink hasPrefix:@"http://"] ) {
    NSString* oldLink = storyLink;
    storyLink = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:oldLink];
}
```

Chris: when you create the NSURL from the NSString, store that in a local variable and log that.  If I'm right, the NSURL creation failed and you're currently passing NULL into -openURL.  Have you tried opening a known-good NSURL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

Comment: I am indeed!When I try to open Apple it works and then the rest of the time, my link shows up as null. What do I do?

Comment: I got it to work by encoding the string with NSASCII before creating a UL, but now my table shows up blank when I change the path to feeds.feedburner.com/paradisebeats

does feedburner (atom) parse things differently?

Comment: Also tried "http://www.paradisebeats.com/feeds/posts/default" which is the link to the rss feed on the site, but no go

Answer (score 1):

Your link, as showing in your log is

> technobuffalo.com/companies/apple/…

instead of

> **http**://technobuffalo.com/companies/apple/…

Please notice the difference: the "http://" prefix.

Your URL strings are missing the "http://" prefix.

Comment: It seems that some part of the URL is illegal. I see you remove blanks and "\n", so it may still contain other illegal characters/combinations. Can you please post an entire URL that doesn't get opened (from NSLog of course).

Comment: http://feeds.feedburner.com/paradisebeats/

Can you see if you can download a a feed from this URL?

(and add http:// on the front because it gets taken off here)